# How can I use kbhit function in Mingw64?

Tags: c++, mingw, kbhit

I'm developing some game in Mingw, (It's school assignment so that i cannot change the development environment).
I have to consider keypress event, so i used kbhit(), included in conio headerfile.
However, it doesn't normally work in Mingw64 setting. (I can include conio.h, but it doesn't work at all)
Can you guys give any solution? (I can't use external sources or headerfile)

Comment: What did you try and what did you get? Any error reproducible code?

Comment: A `conio` header is not a part of the C++ standard library and not a part of MinGW. In addition to what @LinuXMan said, where does the idea of using it come from?

Comment: My TA just said me that i can use windows header and GetAsyncKeyState function. Thank you for comments!